# Difference between fulltext boolean mode and like in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created full text search in my database

its showing wrong result for in Boolean mode search

```
SELECT * FROM catalgo_auto_productdetails  WHERE product_name like '%htc%'
```

showing correct result

```
SELECT * FROM catalgo_auto_productdetails  WHERE MATCH (`product_name`)
     AGAINST ('htc' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

showing empty result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented under [Fine-Tuning MySQL Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html):

> The minimum and maximum lengths of words to be indexed are defined by the [**`innodb_ft_min_token_size`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_min_token_size) and [**`innodb_ft_max_token_size`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_max_token_size) for **`InnoDB`** search indexes, and [**`ft_min_word_len`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) and [**`ft_max_word_len`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_max_word_len) for **`MyISAM`** ones. After changing any of these options, rebuild your **`FULLTEXT`** indexes for the change to take effect. For example, to make two-character words searchable, you could put the following lines in an option file:
>
> ```
> [mysqld]
> innodb_ft_min_token_size=2
> ft_min_word_len=2
> ```
>
> Then restart the server and rebuild your **`FULLTEXT`** indexes. For **`MyISAM`** tables, note particularly the remarks regarding [**myisamchk**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/myisamchk.html) in the instructions following this list.